# Did Edrio and Benthic appear both in Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Knowing that Edrio and his eggmate Benthic are phenotypically identical Tognaths, I think that the only way to know who is who it is by their different attire and (probably) voice.

I found in the web a picture of Edrio and Benthic (of unknown origin). It's probably a behind scene photo, thus, I ask if both are depicted in the movie *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story* (2016), sharing or not a scene.

[image: Picture of Edrio and Benthic]

Comment: See https://dorksideoftheforce.com/2016/12/12/star-wars-rogue-one-cast-list/.  Edrio is listed.  Benthic is not.

Comment: Other sources reference him in Rogue One.  IMDB shows no references at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they both appear together in the scene in which Andor and Jyn Erso are blindfolded, prior to their transportation to Saw Garrera.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Valorum. Great catch!